# URL to an unnamed part of a web page

Tags: html

I'd like to refer to a specific part of a web page which I am not the author of, and which is not tagged with the `NAME` attribute.  The specification of the part I have in mind could be made, e.g., as the location a certain word appears, and which could be manually reached via a `FIND` operation.  I imagine something like

> http://somesite.com#search-for:foo-bar

Is there some feature in HTML allowing for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You can only link to elements with an `id` and `a` elements with a `name`.